# How to find out or where to specify path of the JavaEE project?

Tags: path, jakarta-ee

I develop Java EEapplication and I have to create some files in the src folder in the my application. But I dont where or how to specify the path. I want my application to be portable. It means just to say TestProject/src/.... and not C:/bla/bla/TestProject/src/...

do we specify this in some app file like web.inf, meta-inf or its just some trick.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to load the resource via the classloader using [ClassLoader.getResourseAsStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29). Since you said that you place it in your src file then you just need to make sure it gets packaged into your jar or if you are using a war then place it under WEB-INF/classes. From there you can just use the [ClassLoader.getResourseAsStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29). The advantage of this is that anywhere your jar/war goes the file goes and you don't ever have to worry about the file location because the ClassLoader reads relative to the source of the archive file. For examples on how use it or more classpath loading techniques you can read this [article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-08/01-qa-0808-property.html). (Page two has the example you need)

Answer (score 0):

If its is a web application, you can find out the location of the temporary directory then create your files there. Eg

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
   throws Exception {

   File f = (File)getServletContext().getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir");
   if (f != null) {
     // Do something with f
   } else {
     // We don't have a temporary directory. Fall back to a preconfigured directory 
     // from web.xml <init-param>
   }
}
```

See [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=170963&seqNum=6).

Comment: and what if I have JSF application? Can I get the real path from a simple class? OK, there possibility to get faces context like: FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); but about the real path I have no idea.

Comment: You do something like this FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); ServletContext sc = (ServletContext)fc.getExternalContext().getContext();

Comment: ok, it works. But Im still little confused.

Actualy I do this. In runtime I generate classes, I compile them and then I use them. Where do you prefer to create them? in "src" folder and compile to build/classes? And after how to get the absolute path to them?

Comment: also with you code I get C:\......\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\TestPorject\